# How to send HTTP client request with Authentication Challenge in iPhone programming

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, http, nsurlconnection

I am trying to send http request with authentication security.It will give the response in JSON format.I am looking for any tutorial or sample code for sending http request to get response.I have already searched but not getting any useful tutorial.Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need tutorial for parsing JSON on iOS or what?

Comment: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: maybe take a look on AFNetworking on gitHub

Comment: @preetam this library is not supported anymore as far as I know. This is why I suggest AFNetworking

Comment: @viperking: why,I am using.is any problem?

Comment: @preetam take a look at the top of the page you posted: *Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let say you want to get data from the service and you have URl For That so following method will get the data from the server within Url Given

-(NSString *)getDataFromService:(NSString *)strUrl{

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
NSString *response;


ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];



[request setDelegate:self];
[request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:USERNAME
                                      andPassword:PASSWORD];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];

if (!error) {
   response = [request responseString];

}
else
{

    response=nil;
}

return response;
```

}

so in response String you have the response data from the server of given url.

for this you need to donwload the library from github named as ASIHTTPRequest here is the link

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 0):

You can implement "NSURLConnectionDataDelegate". In you .h file do something like

```
@interface youClass : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

In your .h file implement the delegate method of "NSURLConnectionDataDelegate"

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:    (NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
      //    NSLog(@"canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:");
      return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod         isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:    (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    //    NSLog(@"didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:");
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential     credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]     forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
     //    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    //    NSLog(@"Recived data!!!");
}
```

Hope this helps. :)